# How to show the page when background image fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image and I want to use `$(documnet).load()` to set an event that shows the page whenever the image is fully loaded. How can I do that?

My HTML code:

```
<html>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </script>
        <style>
              body{
                background-image: url('../images/heart-beat.png');
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    <body>
    Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are new to javascript and jQuery, I recommend the [jQuery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/), especially the page about [different ways to run scripts](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/running-code/).

Comment: I would try something else. Have an empty page or a loader. Then load the image via ajax and on success display everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/3915110). Basically, you cannot detect the load event of a background image (it's supposed to happen in the background!) so you load the image using the image element, and then once it is loaded (and assumably cached in the browser) you set it to be the background image for the body.

Answer (score 0):

please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013769/only-load-the-background-image-when-it-has-been-fully-loaded?rq=1) .it's better to give background image to image tag in to ur body

```
<img src='yourimage' id='img'/>
```